# Querying 4 tables with inner join codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

i have 4 tables jobs, company, employment_type & job_category the primary key for each are job_id, com_id, type_id, job_cat_id, but (com_id, type_id, job_cat_id) are foreign key to jobs table.

my query without active record work perfectly and it is as follow

```
select company.com_id, company.company_name, jobs.job_id, jobs.title, jobs.opening_date, jobs.closing_date, jobs.number_of_pos, employment_type.type_id, employment_type.type, job_category.job_cat_id,  job_category. category from company inner join jobs on company.com_id=jobs.com_id inner join employment_type on employment_type.type_id=jobs.type_id inner join job_category on job_category.job_cat_id=jobs.job_cat_id
```

but if i try to use codeiginiter active record such as

```
  $this->db->select('company.com_id, company.company_name, jobs.job_id, jobs.title, jobs.opening_date, jobs.closing_date, jobs.number_of_pos, employment_type.type_id, employment_type.type, job_category.job_cat_id,  job_category. category');
            $this->db->from('company');
            $this->db->join('jobs','company.com_id=jobs.com_id','inner');
            $this->db->join('employment_type', 'employment_type.type_id=jobs.type_id','inner');
            $this->db->join('job_category', 'job_category.job_cat_id=jobs.job_cat_id','inner');
            $this->db->order_by('job_id','DESC');
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
```

i end up with the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`) INNER JOIN `jobs` ON `company`.`com_id`=`jobs`.`com_id` INNER JOIN `employmen' at line 1

SELECT `company`.`com_id`, `company`.`company_name`, `jobs`.`job_id`, `jobs`.`title`, `jobs`.`opening_date`, `jobs`.`closing_date`, `jobs`.`number_of_pos`, `employment_type`.`type_id`, `employment_type`.`type`, `job_category`.`job_cat_id`, `job_category`.` category FROM (`company`) INNER JOIN `jobs` ON `company`.`com_id`=`jobs`.`com_id` INNER JOIN `employment_type` ON `employment_type`.`type_id`=`jobs`.`type_id` INNER JOIN `job_category` ON `job_category`.`job_cat_id`=`jobs`.`job_cat_id` ORDER BY `job_id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is why I don't use the codeigniter functions and only use $this->db->query() with my own written query...

Comment: Well for testing purpose you can use [this](http://brettdewoody.com/labs/active-check/index.php) to save your time

Answer (score 0):

you have a space in `job_category. category` remove that and you should be golden

Comment: Thanks SNAG you won't believe i look into it 4 hrs without seeing the space am good to go thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Format your query like this

```
$data   =   array(
                'company.com_id', 
                'company.company_name', 
                'jobs.job_id', 
                'jobs.title',
                'jobs.opening_date', 
                'jobs.closing_date', 
                'jobs.number_of_pos', 
                'employment_type.type_id', 
                'employment_type.type', 
                'job_category.job_cat_id',  
                'job_category.category'
);

$this->db->select($data);
$this->db->from('company');
$this->db->join('jobs','company.com_id=jobs.com_id','inner');
$this->db->join('employment_type', 'employment_type.type_id=jobs.type_id','inner');
$this->db->join('job_category', 'job_category.job_cat_id=jobs.job_cat_id','inner');
$this->db->order_by('job_id','DESC');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```